# sextic reciprocity and divisibility question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Regarding the question if

$p|(2^{2(p-1)/6}+2^{(p-1)/6}+1) $ where $p$ is a prime of the form $7\mod 8 $

That is how far I got:

$2^{(p-1)/6} \mod\ p\equiv x $

if the solution of $x^6\  mod\ p\equiv 1\ or \ (p+1)/2 $ is $1 \ or -1$ then it is easy to show that $p\nmid (2^{2(p-1)/6}+2^{(p-1)/6}+1)$.

I got stuck since I don't know if  other solutions of $x^6\  mod\ p\equiv 1\ or \ (p+1)/2 $ will guarantee $p\nmid (2^{2(p-1)/6}+2^{(p-1)/6}+1)$.

Any help?

Comment: What's wrong with the criterion that for a prime $p\equiv 7 \pmod{8}$ we have $$p \nmid (2^{2(p-1)/6} + 2^{(p-1)/6} + 1) \iff p \nmid 2^{(p-1)/6} - 1\,?$$

Comment: Thank you. What if we don't know if $2^{(p-1)/6} \mod\ p\equiv 1$ or not? Also do you have  a proof of the criterion?

Comment: We know that $p \mid 2^{(p-1)/2} - 1$, and $2^{(p-1)/2} = (2^{(p-1)/6}-1)\cdot (2^{2(p-1)/6} + 2^{(p-1)/6} + 1)$. The $\gcd$ of the two factors is either $1$ or $3$, so $p$ cannot divide both, hence it divides exactly one factor. Whether the criterion is helpful depends on what you want it for. Computationally, it is slightly less work to check the $2^{(p-1)/6}-1$ factor than the other one (_very_ slightly). If you want something for theoretical purposes, I have no idea whether that's anything useful.

Comment: Thank you, I'm stuck at your "The gcd of the two factors is either 1 or 3" statement.Forgive my ignorance...

Comment: $A^2 + A + 1 = (A-1)(A+2) + 3$, so $\gcd (A-1, A^2+A+1) = \gcd(A-1,3)$.

Comment: But in this case A is congruent to 2 mod 3